Can police stop you to check your paperwork in Michigan with little or no cause?
What I mean for example is if a police officer notices a bulge in your jacket and takes it for a gun and asks you to show a CPL. Would you have to show it? Another example is if you were just walking down the street and the police wanted to get your ID because you were in proximity to a crime or something of the sort. Since it may depend on state we’ll say it’s in Michigan.

What is a CPL?  Some sort of firearms license?

@phoog CPL = Concealed Pistol License.

Do people usually carry their permit to carry a concealed weapon? Michigan permits open carry and also accepts the carry permits issued by any state. Stopping someone with a bulge seems like a low-benefit police action.

@DavidSmith, "Do people usually carry their permit to carry a concealed weapon?"  Generally, yes. Just like you are required to carry your driver's license when you drive.


In the State of Michigan, there is no Stop and ID law. That means a
police officer can’t demand to see your identification unless they
have reasonable suspicion that a crime has been committed.
Being forced to produce identification in situations where the police
may be unable to prove reasonable cause for suspicion is more than
just a procedural error. Being illegally forced to show your ID is a
potentially significant legal issue, one that may be used to
invalidate criminal charges or to have a legal case dismissed.

(Source)
This is consistent with the general rule of U.S. Constitutional law that "reasonable suspicion" is required to make what is known as a "Terry stop" after the name of the U.S. Supreme Court case establishing that rule of constitutional law.
Reasonable suspicion has to be grounded in objective, articulable facts, rather than a mere random search or hunch. But, it need not rise to the level of probable cause to believe that you have committed a crime. And, a "Terry stop" must be brief, a few moments of asking you to clarify what superficially seems suspicious or to issue a traffic ticket or citation, without a full fledged search or arrest.

Terry Stop because that rule was coined in Terry v. Ohio, 392 U.S. 1 (1968)

However, the CPL/CCW law seems different.  I'm not sure if this is the current law, but if it is, it appears (to no lawyer me) that in Michigan they can ask about CPL/CCW

@PeterM I'd never heard of a Concealed Pistol License and assumed (wrongly) that a CPL was some weird Michigan name for a driver's license. I have no idea what MI gun control laws are like.

Michigan permits open carry and accepts all state-issued permits for concealed carry.

@PeterM, Police can generally always ask, you are only required to furnish the CPL + ID if you have one, and are carrying.  If the bulge is a sandwich you can refuse the request.

It seems like this would be analogous to stopping any car and asking to see the driver's license, since they could be driving with an expired license. The fact that you appear to have a concealed weapon does not provide reasonable suspicion that you're carrying it illegally, just as driving a car does not cause suspicion that you're driving without a valid license.

But it wouldn't take much of a plus to change that and provide a basis for reasonable suspicion rather than probable cause. For example, a report of an incident in the area involving someone with a vaguely similar description.

Could that apply to the analogous situation? Could someone report that someone is driving a Honda with an expired license", and they could then legally pull over all Hondas?

DV for not adding any useful information to the concise existing answer.  (i.e. why did you even bother?)

@MichaelHall It possibly could have been a comment, but I recently got out of a ban for posting answers in comments.

stopping the car to ask for the driver's license is illegal under Terry v Ohio, unless there's suspicion that the owner of the car has no license.
